# Why Heroky reset my file "data.json" everyday?

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I made a discordJs bot which saves data in a file.
Everything is hosted on Heroku and all works good.
But everyday, Heroku reset my file.

Why can't i keep my files everyday ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the full explanation from Heroku docs:

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
>   the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
>   shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
>   filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
>   container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
>
> In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a
>   process known as "Cycling".
>
> These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for
>   persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we
>   recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a
>   dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files). If
>   you don't want to set up an account with AWS to create an S3 bucket we
>   also have addons here that handle storage and processing of static
>   assets https://elements.heroku.com/addons

Source: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted